# how to restrict access to public files with apache and php?

Tags: javascript, php, apache

Previosly, the website was hosted on private network, so there was no need to restrict access to files.

The site is one page with long table, and each line corisponde to one file (with the same id). When you click the line JS loads the file. the files are publicly avalable, so JS could load them without AJAX.

Now, the site is mooved to be hosted on the internet.

I can restrict the access to the main page with PHP, but i cant moove the files to unaccessable folders, becouse JS will not be able to load.

I tried to redirect all traffic to a LOGIN page where PHP will decide which is allowd like this:

In apache:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /login.php
```

in login.php: if not outhorized: will be dissmissed, and if outhrized, will be reidrected back to original file:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['request_url']);
```

The problem that i don't know how to let apache know not to redirect those ware already confirmed. so now

```
apache redirect to login.php -> login.php redirect to original page -> apache redirects to login.php -> and so on...
```

i tried to set env varable in php:

```
$_ENV['stop_rewrite'] = true;
```

and in apache:

```
<if !stop_rewrite>
 RewriteRule (.*) /login.php
</if>
```

but i get a 500 error..

any idea how to get around the problem?

Comment: Last time I did anything like this it was with [a mod_perl authentication handler](https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/security.html). I don't think there's a PHP equivalent though.

Answer (score -1):

Add below line in your .htaccess file located in root directory :

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: The question is asking how to add authentication to a bunch of URLs, not how to turn off the display of directory indexes for directories that don't have an index document.